# Submit jobs using API Client Library for Python?

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Does [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) support creation and deletion of pods and jobs on google container engine?

Answer (score 5):

Given that Kubernetes comes with a Swagger spec (1.2, not the latest version), you can use swagger-codegen to generate an Python API client for it.

Here is an example to generate Python API client using https://generator.swagger.io:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type:application/json" -d '{"swaggerUrl":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/master/api/swagger-spec/v1.json"}' https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/python
```

which returns a JSON with an URL to download the zipped Python API client.

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators

If you need help with swagger codegen or the Python API client, please open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Answer (score 1):

No. The client library for python contains functions for interacting with the Google Container Engine API but not the Kubernetes API. The Kubernetes API uses a standard [swagger](http://swagger.io) specification, so it should be possible to generate a python client library. There is also [pykube](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykube/0.5.1) if you want to experiment with a existing client library.