# appengine frontend to kubernetes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup a flask app on google app engine that will be something of a frontend management console for google container engine. Google has put out working APIs to spin up a container cluster, but it does not look like they have put out (python) APIs to administer kubernetes. That is, everything needed implement services, pods, RCs etc. seems to be setup to run through bash scripting. This is not compatible with the restrictions of google's app engine.

Is there a commonly accepted solution/package for this? Would it make more sense to abandon appengine in favor for a managed VM (not ideal)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [Submit jobs using API Client Library for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574607/submit-jobs-using-api-client-library-for-python/34579648#34579648), the Kubernetes API uses a standard swagger specification, so it should be possible to generate a python client library. There is also [pykube](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykube/0.5.1) if you want to experiment with a existing client library.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quite see this question.